# `_mm_pow_ps `and similar functions are not recognized

Tags: c, clion, sse, intrinsics, avx

As a part of an assignment, I'm supposed to create functions that calculate some formulas while using intrinsics as much as possible. In one such part, I'm supposed to calculate the cubed root of a floating-point number held in an __m128 vector. However, every method that could seemingly help won't work, as the compiler does not recognize them, such functions include `_mm_cbrt_ps`, `_mm_pow_ps`, and `_mm_log_ps`.
In my CMakeList file I have the following

```
project(untitled9 C ASM)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

include_directories(.)
add_executable(untitled9 formulas.h main.c formula1.c formula2.s)


target_compile_options(untitled9 PRIVATE -march=native -mavx2 -msse2) 

target_link_libraries(untitled9 m)

set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-no-pie")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
```

Do I need to change or add a flag here or something along those lines? I'll add that I'm using VMware to simulate Linux and I'm using Clion.

Comment: I suspect that to get those "intrinsics" which are actually mostly Intel specific library code you will need to include their Short Vector Math Library (SVML) or GCC's equivalent which may not be on your default library search path.  See [Intel site SVML info](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-10/intrinsics-for-square-root-and-cube-root-ops.html) for details.